# Epimorphism and surjection

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory, manifolds, epimorphisms

I have seen on
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Epimorphism.html

> A morphism $f:Y \to X$ in a category is an epimorphism if, for any two morphisms $u,v:X\to Z, uf=vf$ implies $u=v$. 
>   In the categories of sets, groups, modules, etc., an epimorphism is the same as a surjection, and is used synonymously with "surjection" outside of category theory.

My question is, if $X,Y$ are manifolds,  epimorphism and surjection are the same? Because I found that, one usually uses "surjection" for a map between two non-specific manifolds $M, N$, and "epimorphism" for a map between tangent bundle $TM, TN$.

Comment: This "etc." can be extremely misleading ; it is not true in the categories of monoids or rings !

Comment: I don't think so : for example, a morphism with dense image should have this property too.

Comment: Thank you @Arnaud D, in the case of manifold, are they the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $X=(0,2\pi)$, $Y=S^1$, and $f(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$. Then $f$ is not surjective, since $(1,0)\notin f\bigl((0,2\pi)\bigr)$. But $f$ *is* an epimorphism, because if $Z$ is another manifold, and $u,v\colon S^1\longrightarrow Z$ are differentiable maps such that $u\circ f=v\circ f$, then $u=v$, because the image of $f$ is dense in $S^1$.

Comment: By the same argument, in the category of topological spaces and continuous maps an epimorphism doesn't need to be surjective.

Comment: Thank you both, and vice versa, is a surjective map always an epimorphism?

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion $i : [0,1) \hookrightarrow [0,1]$ seems to have this property. Indeed, if $u,v : [0,1] \to M$ are smooth maps which agree on $[0,1)$ then we should have $u(1) = v(1)$ by continuity.